# ¿Como modificar un dato dentro de un array multidimensional en php?

Tags: php, array, formularios, array-bidimensional

Para empezar no tengo claro si tengo que hacer un *array multidimensional* o se puede hacer de otra manera. Mi código  consiste en una agenda de tareas en las que añado tareas y se van sumando a una lista. Yo añadí una variable para saber decir si estan completadas o no. Al insertarlas siempre aparecen en **NO** pero tengo un botón para completarlas y cambiar ese valor con **SI**, y *ese cambio no me queda claro si es con array multi o no*, y si es con ello tampoco sabría como proceder con mi código.

Tengo creado el apartado para si pulsamos ese botón pero he intentado varias cosas y no se como seguir. Me obligan a hacer todo en un sola página.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    session_start(); //inicio sesion para guardar los datos
    if(!isset($_SESSION['datos'])){ // si no hay datos creeamos el array
        $_SESSION['datos'] = array(); 
        $listado= array();
    }else{
      $listado=$_SESSION['datos']; // si ya hay datos los agrega a listado
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['tarea'])){ // si hemos introducido la tarea la saneamos y la introducimos en el listado
      $nuevatarea= filter_input(INPUT_POST,'tarea', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      array_push($listado, $nuevatarea);
      $_SESSION['datos']=$listado;
    }else{
        $tareavacia="(*)Nombre Obligatorio";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['borrarTarea']) && !empty($_POST['selecTarea'])){
        $numeroTarea=($_POST['selecTarea'])-1; // restamos uno porque los array empiezan por 0
        unset($listado[$numeroTarea]);
        $listado= array_values($listado);
        $_SESSION['datos']=$listado;                   
    }
     if(isset($_POST['completarTarea']) && !empty($_POST['selecTarea'])){
        $numeroTarea=($_POST['selecTarea'])-1; // restamos uno porque los array empiezan por 0
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
                <input type="text" name="tarea"/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['añadir']) && empty($_POST['tarea'])){
                        echo $tareavacia;
                    }
                ?>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="añadir">Añadir Tarea</button>
                <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>  
            </fieldset>           
            <br>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                <?php 
                    if(count($listado)==0){
                        echo "No hay tareas";
                    }else{
                        ?>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                               <th>Número de Tarea</th>
                                <th>Tarea</th>
                                <th>Completado</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                for($i=0; $i < count($listado); $i++){
                                    $contador=$i+1;
                                    $completada="No";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>$contador</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$listado[$i]</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$completada</td>";
                                }         
                    ?>  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
            </fieldset>  

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="selecTarea">Num Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="selecTarea" min="1" max="<?= count($listado) ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="completarTarea" id="completarTarea" value="Tarea Completada"> 
                    <input type="submit" name="borrarTarea" id="borrarTarea" value="Tarea Borrada"/>
                    <br><!-- comment -->
                    <input type="button" id="vaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda"/>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Primero:**
Hay que controlar si se presiona un boton, esto evitara que insertes o borres tareas al recargar la pagina.

**Segundo:**
Debes almacenar `nombre de la tarea / estado` de la tarea, creando un `array` de `arrays asociativos`

Asi cada linea que agregues al `array` deberas hacerlo de la siguiente manera `array[] = $nuevaFila` donde `$nuevafila` es un array asociativo, por cada elemento que agregas **php** automaticamente le asigna un id  `autonumerico` iniciando en 0 hasta n

ejemplo:

```
$tareas = [];
$tarea[] = [
  "nombre"=>"Esta esuna tarea",
  "estado"=>"No"
];
```

**Dicho esto el codigo quedaria asi :**

```
<?php
session_start(); 

//Iniciamos los datos
$listado= array();
if(!isset($_SESSION['datos']))  $_SESSION['datos'] = array(); 
else  $listado=$_SESSION['datos']; 

//Control boton borrar
if(isset($_POST["btnborrar"])){
    $key = $_POST["btnborrar"];
    unset($listado[$key]);
    $_SESSION['datos'] = $listado;

}

//control boton completar
if(isset($_POST["btncompletar"])){
    $key = $_POST["btncompletar"];
    $listado[$key]["estado"] = "Si";
    $_SESSION['datos'] = $listado;

}
//control boton vaciar
if(isset($_POST["btnvaciar"])){
    $listado= array();
    $_SESSION['datos'] = $listado;
}

//control boton agregar
if(isset($_POST["btnagregar"])){
    $nuevatarea= filter_input(INPUT_POST,'tarea', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $listado[] = [
         "nombre" =>$nuevatarea,
         "estado" =>"No"
    ];
    $_SESSION['datos']= $listado;
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
        <form method="POST" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
                <input type="text" name="tarea"/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['añadir']) && empty($_POST['tarea'])){
                        echo $tareavacia;
                    }
                ?>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="btnagregar">Añadir Tarea</button>
                <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>  
            </fieldset>    
        
        <br>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                <?php 
                    if(count($listado)==0){
                        echo "No hay tareas";
                    }else{
                ?>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                               <th>Número</th>
                                <th>Tarea</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($listado as $key => $tarea) {
                                    $nombre = $tarea['nombre'];
                                    $estado = $tarea['estado'];
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>$key</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$nombre</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$estado</td>";
                                    echo "<td>
                                    <button type='submit' name='btncompletar'  value='$key'>Completar </button>
                                    <button type='submit' name='btnborrar'  value='$key'>Borrar </button>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                              

                    ?>  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                   
            </fieldset>  

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <br><!-- comment -->
                    <input type="submit" name="btnvaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <?php   }  ?>   
            </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```